# Preview an archive contents without extracting it

Tags: terminal, archive

`less` command on Ubuntu allows to peek inside different kinds of archives from terminal. For example, all of these commands would show me the list of files in each of the four archives:

```
less archive.zip
less archive.tar.gz
less archive.tar.bz2
less archive.7z
```

On MacOS, I can use `vim` for this. However, this is less convenient, because Vim requires four buttons to be pressed to exit it (`:q` + return) instead of one (`q`).

Is there an equivalently fast way to see list of files in archives for MacOS?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Manually

- **zip**: `unzip -v FILE.zip`
- **tar.gz**: `tar tvzf FILE.tar.gz`
- **tar.bz2**: `bunzip2 -c FILE.tar.bz2 | tar tvf -`
- **.7z**: `7z l FILE.7z`

PS: For `.7z` you need to run `brew install p7zip` first

### Extend `less` to work the same way it does under Linux

- Install `lesspipe`

  ```
   brew install lesspipe
  ```
- Add the following lines to `.bashrc` (or the profile of whatever shell you use)

  ```
   brew_prefix=$(brew --prefix)
   if [[ -x ${brew_prefix}/bin/lesspipe.sh ]]; then
       export LESSOPEN="|${brew_prefix}/bin/lesspipe.sh %s"
       export LESS_ADVANCED_PREPROCESSOR=1
   fi
  ```
- Source `.bashrc` or open a new terminal tab

Answer (score 16):

I was able to successfully accomplish what GEdgar posted using BetterZipQL (available here:  https://macitbetter.com/BetterZip-Quick-Look-Generator/).  Just select an archive and tap the spacebar.

[image: BetterZipQL]

Confirmed it works with 7z and rar archives, and also works on archives at least 700 MB in size, which was the largest I had handy.

Comment: This feature was the main reason I installed BetterZip. Very convenient.

Comment: Incredible. Love the feature to view hidden files --> which in my case was capturing the `__MACOSX` folder that I didn't want in the archive.

Answer (score 3):

MacOS and a third party app called The Unarchiver work together to make this happen.

Installing that app adds a Quick Look plug in that lets Finder view the names of the files in a ZIP archive without extracting and without launching the third party application.

Since it takes more than three clicks and installing another program, perhaps this is not what you want.

The images are from macOS Mojave 10.14.5

In the Finder, select the ZIP file.
[image: ready.zip]
Hit the space bar.  You see a window about the ZIP file.
[image: quicklook contents of a zip file]
In that window, click on the little triangle ▶︎ to see the list of files contained in the archive.
[image: expanding the folder hierarchy]
If there are folders within folders, use the new triangle to see them.
[image: fully expanded folder hierarchy of Quick Look plug in browsing a zip file]

If the ZIP file is encrypted, you may see less about it.

Comment: It my interface this window looks different. The button on the right is called "Uncompress". And on the left I see a giant icon of an archive. But no way to press it and see the tree.

Comment: Interesting.  So maybe this interface is supplied by "The Unarchiver", which is free in the Mac App Store.  Maybe you have to set The Unarchiver as the default way to open ZIP files?

Comment: I've tried setting The Unarchiver as the default, but I still can't see the contents. That said, my archive is pretty big.

Comment: Try it with  small archive and see if that works.  Maybe reboot after changing the default.

Comment: This doesn't work on macOS 12 Monterey. There is no preview of the file contents after pressing space.

Comment: It is a Quick Look plug in (there are several like The Unarchiver) but super solid answer, forgive any errors I may have made in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could install a quicklook plugin for previewing compressed files such as the open-source [qlZipInfo](https://github.com/srirangav/qlZipInfo) - which supports many formats including .zip, .tar, .xz etc. Once installed you just select the file in Finder and hit space bar to preview the contents.